# HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager() использование

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

Как правильно использовать HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager()? Нужно ли его оборачивать в using? Или он сам закрывает соединение? Вопрос возник из-за логов бд, есть ощущение, что этот метод плодит подключения и не закрывает их, в итоге получаем кучу зомби коннектов и мертвую бд.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечаю сам себе. Его нужно заворачивать в using, т.к. он (или EF6) не закрывает за собой соединение. Можно сделать элегантнее с использованием Middleware в Owin.
Для этого идем в IdentityConfig и добавляем в метод Configuration следующий код:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    context.GetUserManager<AppUserManager>().Context.Dispose();
});
```

P.S. Я держу DbContext в AppUserManagar'e, у вас его может не быть.